# Why it's needed to "source" some Vim plugins?

Tags: python, vim, plugins, tags, ctags

From [autotag.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1343):

> **install details**
>
> Simply source the file
> autoTag.vim from your .vimrc file.
> This utility will (obviously) only
> work when using vim that's been
> compiled with python support.

Is this needed because this is a Python plugin in vim, instead of a vimscript? Aren't plugins in `.vim/plugin` loaded automatically?

This plugin only works when I source it. Is this behavior expected because I'm using [pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference: if you place it in `.vim/plugin`, you don't need to source it from somewhere else.

### Addendum

As Randy Morris explains in the comments, with `pathogen.vim`'s magic, the equivalent plugin path to put the script in would actually be `.vim/bundle/autotag/plugin`.

Comment: The plugin doesn't work unless I source it in my vimrc. I've edited my question with more information.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually being loaded as a plugin? Is the script listed in `:scriptnames`?

Comment: Is listed in :scriptnames only when I source it in my vimrc, not when I just place autotag.vim in ~/.vim/bundle/autotag/autotag.vim. Other plugins with pathogen work. I'm going to test it inside plugin directory.

Comment: You have to put it in `.vim/plugin` for it to be loaded as a plugin, obviously.

Comment: @Piet: He is using pathogen, which means it doesn't have to go in ~/.vim/plugin, but it does have to go in a plugin directory.

Comment: @Somebody: Put it in ~/.vim/bundle/autotag/plugin/autotag.vim instead.

Comment: @Randy, you're right. My bad. ~/.vim/bundle/autotag/plugin/autotag.vim works.

Comment: @Randy, if you answer my question, I can mark it as accepted since you solved my problem, but if you don't I'm going to accept Piet Delport if he edits his question adding your solution and since the answer about "source" command seems correct.

Comment: @Somebody: His answer is also correct, and more correct for the wording of the question.  I'd suggest accepting his.

Comment: @Piet: I'm going to accept your answer, it would be interesting if you edit your answer containing Randy's solution so other users wouldn't need to read all comments. Thanks Randy!